# Xcode won't show my textfield placeholder text in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uitextfield

When I assign my textfield's placeholder value in the attributes inspector, it won't show in the storyboard, however, when I run a simulator of the application is is there. Is there a setting I'm missing? I just want to be able to see the placeholder text in the editor. Below is a screenshot of xcode and one of the simulator

[image: xcode]

[image]

Comment: I can only confirm this bug on my own system with iOS 11.2, Xcode 9.2, OSX High Sierra. I tried to change colors of the text field to see if this would make the invisible place holder appear.

I made a small proj to demostrate it;
 https://github.com/eSpecialized/PlaceHolderBug

Comment: I created an apple bug for this;
https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=35939357
   35939357 placeholder blank in storyboards designer

Comment: Thanks, Bill. I'm confirming this as of 6 Jan 2017 as well.

Comment: I am having a similar issue on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 XCode 9.2

Comment: Can confirm, still having this with XCode 9.2 High Sierra 10.13.2 as 24 Jan 2017

Answer (score 8):

I am having the same issue, fortunately I run a MacBook with Xcode 9.1(9B55) and an iMac with Xcode 9.2(9C40b)

On my MacBook all placeholders show up but on iMac they don't.
So the issue is with xCode 9.2 running High Sierra.

Comment: It happens on my system with iOS 11.2, Xcode 9.2, OSX Sierra

Comment: Had the same issue  with  Xcode 9.2, ,where the place holder not visible in stroyboard as well as on running device too. then i remove the IBOUTLET connection and again connect .its working.